# iOS NSDataDetectors vs NSRegularExpressions - Better approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression, nsdatadetector

I have a scenario that em implementing that I need to extract `URLs` from given `NSStrings`, so i came to find **2 ways** to do so (by the Help of SO :))…

Such that I have a `NSString` like this

```
NSString *someString = @"This is a sample of a http:\/\/www.abc.com\/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
```

and then i can use both these ways to get the `URL` out of the string...

**1st way**

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];
NSLog(@"%@", match);
```

**2nd way**

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:someString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
    NSURL *url = [match URL];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
  }
}
```

My question is which one is better and faster as I have around **400 to 500 `NSStrings`** to parse at an instance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hm... which one is faster -> why not just running both and track via instruments how long it takes. Better: probably the data detector, since Apple will invest in its working. Yet, if for some reasons URLs don't work with the detector your are much more flexibel with your now RegEx.

Comment: @Volker thank you for the info.. will look it up..